# How to pause android translation in mid and resume then

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-animation

In my app, i am playing with android translation animation. I want to translate view from top right of screen to bottom left of the screen. I can translate the view. Now i want to pause the translation for some seconds in mid and then i want resume it. I have tired playing around with different interpolators. Those doesn't give the required result. Can someone tell me how can i achieve this kind of translation?

I am sharing the code that i am using for the translation.

```
 AnimationSet animationSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 2f,
                1f, 2f,
                ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f,
                ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .1f);
        animationSet.addAnimation(scale);
        int size[] = MainActivity.getDisplaySize(this);
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(-1000, 1500, 300, 850);
        animationSet.addAnimation(animation);
        animationSet.setDuration(6000);
        animationSet.setFillAfter(false);
        animationSet.setInterpolator(new FastOutLinearInInterpolator());
        animationSet.setAnimationListener(new MyAnimationListener());
        imageView.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A common solution is to split up the animation into 2 seperate animations.

So you have to start the 2nd animation after your desired pause.

An other approach is to save the play time when you pause with() [getCurrentPlayTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#getCurrentPlayTime())
and restart the animation at this time via [setCurrentPlayTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentPlayTime(long)).

Comment: I liked the second solution but i am using ```AnimationSet``` and ```TranslationAnimation``` class. The methods you pointed out are for ```ValueAnimator``` class.

Comment: Yeah I know. But I don't know if this is possible. I thought you might use the ViewPropertyAnimator instead of the AnimationSet? Should work nice with you current animation?

Comment: Can i scale and translate an view with ```ViewPropertyAnimator```? Sorry i never worked with animatons in android before. I took start with ```Animation```

Comment: Yes. Something lile `view.animate()
    .scaleX(1).scaleY(1).translateX(1000).translateY(1000).start()`

Comment: thanks, but i want to specify the start position as well.

Comment: how would you convert these translation animation ```TranslateAnimation(-1000, 1500, 300, 850)``` to ```ViewPropertyAnimator```

Comment: Start pos: `view.animate().translateX(-1000).translateY(1500).setDuration(0).start().` then `view.animate().translateX(300).translateY(850).setDuration(6000).<scale,etc....>.start())`.